# JBPM 6.0.1 adding custom task to workbench

Tags: task, jbpm, workbench

I've created task in ecplise which calls DB stored procedure. I've written WID and Work Item Handler for this (running from eclipse works). But now I would like to add this task to workbench to let workbench users creating processes with it. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate a little bit more about what you are doing? 
Take a look at this blog post to see if it answer your questions: 
http://salaboy.com/2013/10/22/kie-wb-jbpm-console-ng-configurations/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new process and open it in designer.  After doing that, you should also see a work definitions file being created in the same folder (by default with 4 predefined service tasks), if you open that, add your custom wid and save, reopening the process should show your custom service task in the palette under the service tasks category.

Comment: Yes, but i also need to add work item handler for my own service task and I have no idea how to do it